# Can MVC4 AllowAnonymous coexist with asp.net forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

We have a large ASP.NET application to which we have been adding new 'pages' using MVC3 and more recently MVC4.
I now want to secure the MVC4 pages using the AllowAnonymous attribute on the Controller Actions.

The Web.Config contains an authorization element thus:
    `<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>`

This takes care of the Asp.Net pages. But unfortunately, it also negates the AllowAnonymous attribute for the MVC4 apps.
If I remove the authorization element, then the MVC4 auth works (as with the VS2012 MVC4 template web site), but by removing it, the ASP.Net pages are no longer secured.

Has anybody had any success with a solution that comprises both Asp.Net pages and MVC4?

Comment: Are you using Form authentication?

Comment: Yes, I am using Forms Authentication - that was originally set up for the Asp.Net pages. It looks like this:     `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".XPortal" loginUrl="Admin/Login" timeout="80"/>
    </authentication>`

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding for ASP.Net pages create separate folder and web.config file. Same for MVC pages, create separate folder and web.config file. then add authorization attribute as you need for each.
Such as

```
<authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization> 
    Or
<authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

Comment: I'm actually using that approach as well as using the location element in web.config thus: `<location path="SomeFolder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>`  But using folder locations is not the way to provide authorization for MVC Actions - which are not locations.  I want to embrace the MVC4 AllowAnonymous attribute - and have it coexist with Asp.Net pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have the solution to this problem. 
Originally, for Asp.Net, I was white-listing a few pages that could be accessed without having to log in. i.e. I set `<deny users="?"/>` in the main web.config and then I used the location element to `<allow users="*"/>` for paths that did not require authorization.  In order to use MVC4 authorization, and to have it co-exist with Asp.Net Forms authentication, I suggest the opposite approach, which is to allow access to all users and then black list the paths [folders] of the Asp.Net pages that require authorization in web.config. This will take care of the Asp.Net pages.  For the MVC4 code, the Controller/Action methods can now use the new Authorize and AllowAnonymous attributes.  This is in fact exactly how a pure MVC4 application would work anyway; there would be no `<deny users="?"/>` in the main web.config and the Authorize attribute would be used for securing Actions.  So instead of thinking about converting my Asp.Net application so that it will work with MVC4, I thought about how would I modify an MVC4 application so that it could accommodate Asp.Net pages. I would like to know if there is a preferred way of doing this, so please comment if you have a suggestion.